# Custom Datatable sorting asc and desc doesn't trigger

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a custom sorting function on my Datatable. The console.log in `date-custom-pre` is triggered but the `date-custom-asc` and `date-custom-desc` is not. Does anyone have an idea why? I use datatable 1.10.21

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "date-custom-pre": function(a) {
      var x;
      if ($.trim(a) !== '') {
        var b = a.split('/');
        x = b[2] + b[1] + b[0];
      } else {
        x = Infinity;
      }
      console.log(x)
      return x;
    },
    "date-custom-asc": function(a, b) {
      console.log('asc')
      return a - b;
    },
    "date-custom-desc": function(a, b) {
      console.log('desc')
      return b - a;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those having the same issue, i manage to fix it by turning 'bServerSide' to false. And if you use ServerSide processing, just make your own logic in the server side and not in the js.